# Spark Dataframe IN clause is throwing error

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to apply  IN clause in spark dataframe

```
scala> val filteredDF = resultDF.select("role_id","role","full_name").filter(upper(resultDF("role")).isin(List("DIRECTOR","ACTOR")) )
```

While trying the above command I am getting the error

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List(DIRECTOR, ACTOR)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$anonfun$isin$1.apply(Column.scala:642)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.isin(Column.scala:642)
```

Could some one help me on explaining why I am getting this error and How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass values as separate arguments to `isin`:

```
.isin("DIRECTOR", "ACTOR")
```

Or use *varargs* syntax:

```
.isin(List("DIRECTOR", "ACTOR"): _*)
```

Comment: It works as per your suggestion , you saved lot of my time . Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps !